# rviz over remote dns

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm remote to my master_uri; ie `http://somedns:11311`

I can listen and publish to topics from the master, but I'm unable to list topics in Rviz or Gazebo. I can get it to work over my local network by exporting the local ip of the master to ROS_IP, but i cant resolve the dns server. any suggestions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256245/rviz-over-remote-dns/) by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably don't have bidirectional communications. See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup for some tips on making sure you do have bidirectional comms.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on 2017-03-06**:
i read through all of the above documentation with no luck. I am outside my local network

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-03-06**:
What does no luck mean? Did you try the tests with ncat? did they succeed or fail?

**Comment by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on 2017-03-07**:
nowhere in the above page does it say anything about nmap or ncat. I dont know how to run it across the dns server. Im trying to do some testing while at work another state over.

**Comment by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on 2017-03-07**:
`Ncat: Connection timed out.` when i enter the master uri with or without the port.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-03-07**:
Sorry, I meant `netcat`. The likely issue is that you're cross a NAT and the ports are not open for the various ROS nodes to connect to one another. Most people use a VPN to avoid this issue of port forwarding with ROS.

**Comment by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on 2017-03-08**:
tes `netcat` or `nc` is not communicating. on the robot I typed `nc -l 1234` and on the workstation i typed `nc somedns 1234` and I was unable to send a message to either computer. I even tried a few ports using `-p`. Could i have further complicated things by using virtualbox running ubuntu?

**Comment by [cerebraldad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29250/cerebraldad/) on 2017-03-08**:
I can see the topics listed just cant gather any of the info explicitly.